# How to figure out what the graph of $\frac{\ sin\ x}{x}$

Tags: trigonometry, graphing-functions

Knowing $ y =\ sin\ x$

[image]

What does the graph of $ y = \frac{\ sin\ x}{x}$ look like.

I realise that when $x = 0$ there is a vertical asymptote.

I have tried making $x = 90$ and $x = 270$ and get $y = \frac{1}{90}$ and $y = -\frac{1}{270}$ respectively.

How do I progress from here?

Comment: There's no vertical asymptote.

Comment: Horizontal then. @David Mitra

Comment: You have to use x in radians.

Comment: Why is that? @Sophie

Comment: Hi, have you learnt limits yet? The approximation $\sin{x}/x \approx x$ is only valid for $x$ in radians, not degrees. Also, there's no asymptote at $x=0$.

Answer (score 6):

> **Useful facts:**
>
> - $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x}=1$
> - For $n\in \mathbb{Z}\backslash \{ 0 \} \, , \; \dfrac{\sin n\pi}{n\pi} =0$
> - Envelope of amplitude: $y=\pm \dfrac{1}{x}$
> - $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$ is an even function, i.e. $f(-x)=f(x)$

[image]

Comment: How do you know the envelope of amplitude is $y = \pm \frac{1}{x}$

Comment: Since $-1 \le \sin x \le1$, $$-\frac{1}{x} \le \frac{\sin x}{x} \le \frac{1}{x}$$